# Hashing a hash in redis

Tags: database, redis, nosql

I have been reading around that I **cannot have nested data structures** in redis, and the only way to **include** it is to create a **reference** to it.

If I understand correct, a way to create a **generic struct in redis** would be:

`hmset ARandomStringAsAKey name kostas address milky_way`

I tried to store the **hash** in that way:

`hmset ReferenceTest name kostas ref ARandomStringAsAKey`

and then tried to get it back via:

`hget ReferenceTest ref`

but the only thing I got was a string saying `ARandomKeyAsAString` .

How could I possibly do that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can't get what you want via `hget ReferenceTest ref`.
You shoud:

1. get the key via `hget ReferenceTest ref`
2. get the real data by the value it returns(`ARandomKeyAsAString` )

```
127.0.0.1:6379> hmget ReferenceTest ref
1) "ARandomStringAsAKey"
127.0.0.1:6379> hgetall ARandomStringAsAKey
1) "name"
2) "kostas"
3) "address"
4) "milky_way"
```

**BTW**: We don't store data like that, we transfer `name kostas address milky_way` into a json string, and store it.

```
127.0.0.1:6379> hmset ReferenceTest name kostas data "{\"name\":\"kostas\",\"address\": \"milky_way\"}"
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> hget ReferenceTest data
"{\"name\":\"kostas\",\"address\": \"milky_way\"}"
127.0.0.1:6379>
```